# Client to Site VPN Active Directory Sync

Tags: active-directory, vpn

Hard question to word, but here it goes.

I have a client with a W2k12 essentials Domain Controller that needs to replicate offsite.  We have purchased another 2k12 server to mirror AD, which I've done before and am completely comfy with, but never in this type of scenario.

Basically, I'm trying to use a "remote access (server role)" vpn built into a sonicwall firewall.  I've successfully set up the VPN and have been able to join that DC to the domain (with no AD on it yet) via the client-to-site vpn that's maintained thru windows built in client.

Everything I'm reading says that client-to-site VPNs aren't recommended for offsite DCs in the windows world, but I'm only using this DC as a disaster recovery measure.  It won't be "hosting" any clients at the offsite location, as a matter of fact I'd prefer not to put their home PCs (it's the owners house) on a site-to-site because of the security risk they pose with their unregulated use.

As I see it now, the offsite DC is grabbing a valid IP on the same subnet as the internal LAN at the primary site, and the firewall has basically allowed that IP full access to internal network resources.  I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work except maybe lack of bandwidth, but I might be missing something here because this is a bit of uncharted territory for me.  I'm not even sure if it will require an additional site, again, because I don't know if the existing DC will see this offsite DC as coming from another "subnet".

So, anyone have experience trying to maintain an offsite DC for DR purposes via a client to site VPN?  Am I asking for trouble?  The best 2nd solution I can think of is to have him get another ISP account and do site to site with just the offsite DC on it, but that seems like alot of trouble for what we are doing.

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new AD site for your DR DC and configure a replication schedule, DC should be a GC and DNS role, make sure it replicate regularly so that can be used for DR

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727069.aspx

Comment: So everything I'm seeing regarding Client-to-Site VPNs and offsite replication isn't really playing into it I take it?  Just a few comments I've seen here and there on this type of sync warning specifically of that kind of VPN, but I think it only applies if you have clients on the other end, as they would also need the VPN, but in this case since its just the DC should be a ok?